# How can I write a SQL query that displays grandparents without children (two sub-tables)?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to write a query that returns all of the grandparents that don't have grandchildren.  Here is my table structure:

```
**Grandparents**
id    name
1     lewis

**Parents**
id    name    grandparent_id
10    bob     1    
11    mark    1

**Children**
id    name      parent_id
99    seabass   10
```

Here is the query I have written, but it returns 'grandparents', where one of the parents has 0 children (the gotcha!).  I want return ONLY the grandparents where ALL the parents have 0 children, but I'm not sure of the best way to do this.

```
SELECT grandparents.*
FROM grandparents
LEFT OUTER JOIN parents ON parents.grandparent_id = grandparents.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN children ON children.parent_id = parents.id
WHERE children.id is null
GROUP BY grandparents.id
HAVING count(children.id) = 0;
```

This query returns grandparent 'lewis', but I want to write a query that returns: 0 records in this instance since there are no grandparents without grandchildren.

PS.  A grandparent can't exist alone and have at least one parent in the data.

Comment: Is this a theoretical example?  If you have a real world genealogy database, I'd put all the people in a single table and not have a separate table for "grandparents", who are of course both parents and children in their own right

Comment: Are you sure this returns `Lewis`? This shows it returns [nothing](http://rextester.com/SMSSG95681).

Comment: 2 notes: I also return nothing when I test it. Also you shouldn't have the GROUP BY in this case because you're not aggregating anything.

Comment: use NOT EXISTS for grandchildren... main query inner join with parents and grandparents

Comment: I have modified my real-world example to a simpler more understandable example (ie. I can't modify this table structure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close.  You want to know that there are *never* any children, so the comparison needs to be in the `having` clause:

```
SELECT gp.*
FROM grandparents gp LEFT OUTER JOIN
     parents p
     ON p.grandparent_id = gp.id LEFT OUTER JOIN
     children c
     ON c.parent_id = p.id
GROUP BY gp.id
HAVING COUNT(c.id) = 0;
```

Your query actually answered a slightly different question:  How many grandparents have children that have no children?

Comment: That last statement is a good point. Your sample data is a little slim to show what's really going on.  This would be apparent with a larger more diverse data set

Comment: I added parent Mark, which ends up break your query.  Which is the problem that I am running in to.  If one parent, Mark, has 0 children, then grandparent Lewis is still returned...however, he shouldn't be b/c he has grandchildren.

Comment: @Kamilski81 . . . This is counting all possible grandchildren for the grandparents.  I don't see how this would return any grandparent that has a valid child.  Are you sure you have the right `GROUP BY` keys?

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

NOT EXISTS for grandchildren and main query inner join GRAND and PARENTS (since you want to know granny's with kids (as parents))

```
select distinct g.*
from grandparents g
inner join on parents p
    on g.id = p.grandparent_id
where
   NOT EXISTS (
   select 1 from children c where c.parent_id = p.id
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT gra.*, par.*, chi.*, count(chi.id) AS cnt_children
FROM grandparents AS gra
LEFT JOIN parents AS par ON par.grandparent_id = gra.id
LEFT JOIN children AS chi ON chi.parent_id = par.id
GROUP BY gra.id
HAVING cnt_children = 0;
```

For grandfather `Lewis` (in your question) should indeed return no records.
Having some doubts I tested with two grandfathers too. Results are as expected. So:

1) Grandfather `Lewis` with 4 children and only 2 grandchildren;

2) Grandfather `Andrew` without children and therefore without grandchildren.

The results for **grandparents without any grandchildren at all** are:

[image: Grandparents without grandchildren]

And here (to probe) the results for **grandparents with and without grandchildren** (by just deleting the `HAVING` clause in query):

[image: Grandparents with and without grandchildren]